# Making scroll buttons for a menu/navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, scroll

I have a menu with a lot of options, the idea is to use scroll buttons to navigate left or right(just like viewing your playlist on youtube) controlled by JQuery. I need ideas or suggestions on how to make a functional one that will support any new entries without loosing its functionality. 
Everything i tried so far does work, but doesn't cope with new options or new added links.
Heres the code and the CSS, any suggestions are more than welcome.

HTML:

```
 <body>
        <div id="menu-new">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="sep">
                    <a href="/askthewizard/">Ask The Wizard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/newreleases/">New Releases</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/casestudies/">Case Studies</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sep">
                    <a href="/maintenance/">Maintenance</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/schedule/">Schedule</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/timeclock/">Time Clock</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/payroll/">Payroll</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sep">
                    <a href="/humanresources/">Human Resources</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/application/">Application</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5,
h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong,
sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label,
legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0 none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#menu-new {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #9A1C1C;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu-new ul.menu {
    list-style: none outside none;
    width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-new ul.menu li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
#menu-new ul.menu li.sep {
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 0 12px 0 0;
}
#menu-new ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
}
#menu-new ul.menu li a {
    color: #D9D8B5;
    display: block;
    font: bold 11px/30px 'Arial',sans-serif;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #460100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #9A1C1C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    outline: 0 none;
}
#menu-new ul.menu li a:hover, #menu-new ul.menu li a.active {
    background-color: #DDDCBE;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #222222;
    color: #742C2B;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment. Even tho no one responded i found a way to do it myself in a pretty nice manner, if i might say so. I'll post it here if anyone else bumps up to the same problem. 
As i pondered over some FAQ looking for an answer i got a silly idea, to use anchor system to hover and scroll over the menu. The equation to handle it, was taken and modified from... Well I'm really ashamed that i do not know whom to give the credit for it, i forgot the name or the site of it(but it's pretty simple nevertheless).

And now,

the HTML:

```
<div id="menu-new">
        <div class="contSize">           
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="sep"><a href="#">
                    <a href="/askthewizard/">Ask The Wizard</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/newreleases/">New Releases</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/casestudies/">Case Studies</a>
                </li><a href="#">
                <li class="sep">
                    <a href="/maintenance/">Maintenance</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/schedule/">Schedule</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/timeclock/">Time Clock</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/payroll/">Payroll</a>
                </li><a href="#">
                <li class="sep">
                    <a href="/humanresources/">Human Resources</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/application/">Application</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <a href="/other/">Other</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5,
h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong,
sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label,
legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0 none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#menu-new  {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #9A1C1C;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-new div.contSize{
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-new div.contSize ul.menu {
    list-style: none outside none;
    width: 9000px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#menu-new div.contSize ul.menu li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
#menu-new div.contSize ul.menu li.sep {
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 0 12px 0 0;
}
#menu-new div.contSize ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
}
#menu-new div.contSize ul.menu li a {
    color: #D9D8B5;
    display: block;
    font: bold 11px/30px 'Arial',sans-serif;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #460100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #9A1C1C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    outline: 0 none;
}
#menu-new div.contSize ul.menu li a:hover, #menu-new div.contSize ul.menu li a.active {
    background-color: #DDDCBE;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #222222;
    color: #742C2B;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

The JS(with JQ):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var div = $('#menu-new div.contSize'),
                 ul = $('ul.menu'),
                 ulPadding = 15;

    var divWidth = div.width();
    var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');

    div.mousemove(function(e){

      var ulWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + ulPadding;
      var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;
      div.scrollLeft(left);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [existing solution](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/).

Živ bio Branko!

Comment: Actually thanks to the fact that no one responded, i found a very good way to do it myself. 
Anyway, thanks for the effort.
Hvala :)